# Define location and name of cell statistics output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, statistics

I have a list containing 3 rasters. Running the cell statistics operation on this results in a raster in the default database. My work involves getting the numbers in the count column. I don't want to generate the raster. I just want to extract values from the output in memory if possible.

```
outrast=CellStatistics(rlist,"SUM")
```

output raster name is "sumco_ras" which seems to be a default name. "outrast" is only layer name I think.

Using `SearchCursor` I can extract the values but it is getting complicated when the output raster is in another database with a different name.

Ideal solution would be an output in the memory workspace

Version:10.2.2

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the version of ArcGIS is use.

Answer (score 1):

Cell statistics is intended to be used on a per cell basis. From the [Cell Statistics documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_Cell_Statistics_works/009z00000088000000/):

- Determines the sum of the values in the inputs on a cell-by-cell
  basis.
- If all the inputs are integer, the output is integer. If any of the
  inputs are floating point, the output is floating point.

[image]

You may be more interested in summarizing cells within zones, in which case you would want to use [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) or [Tabulate Area](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w2000000), both of which provide cell counts.